# PHP sleep accuracy

Tags: php, time

I use the following code to see how long a user is on a particular page. I use a hidden image with a src attribute to this script:

```
$timer_seconds = 1;

while(!connection_aborted()) { 
   echo "\n";
   flush();
   sleep(1);
   $timer_seconds++;
}
```

I sometimes find this can be off by 5-10 seconds! I am guessing its the load of the server that effects the timing??

Is there anyway I can make this accurate?

Thanks all for any help.

Comment: It's soooooo annoying when websites do this.

Comment: @chris I'm missing something obvious.. Why is that annoying? Cause the page never stops loading?

Comment: Ya. Not sure why, but it bothers me when the page never finishes loading, even if it functions ok.

Comment: +1 for philosophical job workload esteem: *`just giv the server get its deserved break will ya?`* and let it be loaded when its loaded and don't prolong it artificially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` and `flush` can take time, so your loop sleeps for 1 second + the time spent on `echo` and `flush`.  Try something like:

```
$begin_time = time();
$elapsed_time = 0;

while(!connection_aborted()) {
  echo "\n";
  flush();
  sleep(1);
  $elapsed_time = time() - $begin_time;
}
```

Comment: That seems like a good idea but I tried the above and it seems to still be off by seconds! Your logic is correct but what else can make the elapsed time off by seconds??

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use Javascript do this.
E.g., request something from the client (using Ajax or an image request) on the unload event of the document.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you could make a synchronous ajax call `onbeforeunload` (I know it's not *exactly* ajax any more) to tell how long the user was on the page.

The truth of the matter is that It really doesn't tell you much of anything. Just because someone is on a page doesn't mean they're looking at the page. Just because they look at the page very briefly, doesn't mean they dislike it either.

Comment: I can not use AJAX, this has to be achieved on one page load.

Comment: No, you don't *have* to achieve this on one page load, you **want** to achieve this on one page load. Just remember that you're going to be messing up the user experience when you try to do something as ridiculous as continuing to stream data to the client. It'll also bog your server resources down when you have multiple users on the site at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some nice tools (in javascript) to do that.

http://chartbeat.com

http://analytics.google.com

these are some of used on the company i work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to do this from the server.

Answer (score 0):

as @erjiang said echo and flush take time and after that you put script to sleep... so if for flush was needed 1 seccond and then you sleep 1 seccond thats 2 secconds and you add only one!

solution would be to write a start and end time and then find difference:

```
$start = time();

while(!connection_aborted()){ 
  echo "\n"; //probably not needed...
  flush(); //same probably not needed :)
  sleep(1); //so just a sleep to not continue the code
}

$end = time();
$diff = $end - $start;
$days=floor($diff/86400);
$hours=floor(($diff-($days*86400))/3600);
$minutes=floor(($diff-(($days*86400)+($hours*3600)))/60);
$secconds=floor(($diff-((($days*86400)+($hours*3600))+($minutes*60))));

echo "\n\n".$hours."/".$minutes."/".$secconds;
```

that will do it! ;)